# Service to listen for Firebase data changes

Tags: android, firebase, service, firebase-realtime-database

Basically what I want to do is to set up a service that listens for changes from my Firebase database and shows a notification whenever changes occur.
I have looked up for a solution and I tried to go from there but whenever I want to enter the activity that starts the service my activity won't show up so i don't know if my Service works

This is how my Manifest file looks:

```
 <receiver android:name=".ReceiverCall"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="RESTART_SERVICE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

This is my ReceiverCall class:

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        context.startService(new Intent(context, PopupService.class));;
    }

}
```

My activity that starts the service:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        startService(new   Intent(MainActivity.this, PopupService.class));
        finish();
```

which seems to not show up on the screen.

And this is my service class:

```
public class PopupService extends Service {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    public static DatabaseReference RequestRef;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        RequestRef = database.getReference("counties").child("0").child("name");
        ListenerForRequestDone();
        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent intent = new Intent("RESTART_SERVICE");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void ListenerForRequestDone(){
        RequestRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Database change");
                 //here I want to call the method that opens the notification that some data has changed
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```